# oracle schema sharing , is it possible?

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle19c

Trying to understand if there is any such concept like this in Oracle Database.
Let's say I have two Databases, `Database_A` & `Database_B`
`Database_A` has `schema_A`, is there a way I can attach this schema to `Database_B`?

What I mean by this is if there is a job populating a TABLE_A in `schema_A`, I can see that read-only view in `Database_B`. We are trying to split a big Oracle database into two smaller databases and have a vast PL/SQL code, and trying to minimize the refactoring here.

Comment: Use DB links. DB link is the concept to share anything between 2 databases.

Comment: You can grant select privileges only to those users who you want to see data

Comment: what do you mean by "split"? database links will allow the two databases to see each other, but much of your processing will still take place in whichever database the data actually lives, and you will be adding network latency to your architecture. Are you trying to distribute resource consumption?

Comment: DB links are slow , and does not allow parallel . hence we ruled out this . And looking for alternatives

Comment: @YatinMehta DB links don't have to be slow, but you don't want to push any more data over them than necessary. That's why you would use fast-refresh materialized views to keep a read-only copy of the data in Database_B and not have to run the actual user queries over the network. Materialized views would also support parallelism. There's no other *inexpensive* way than a DB link to join the two databases together.

Comment: @pmdba thanks , but Materialise view do not work when you have date partitioned underlying data , it comes with a lot of baggage of regular refresh and as the data start to grow with date partitions the MV's becomes slow . I was hoping if there was a way o just attach schema between databases , may be there is not .. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

[Sharding](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/shard/oracle-sharding-architecture-and-concepts1.html) might be what you're looking for. The schemas and tables will still logically exist on all databases, but you can arrange the data to be physically stored in specific databases. There might be a way to setup shardspaces, tablespaces, and user default tablespaces in a way where each schema's data is automatically stored in a specific database.

But I haven't actually used sharding. From what I've read, it seems to be designed for *massive* distributed OLTP systems, and it is likely complicated to administer. I'd guess this feature isn't worth the hassle unless you have petabytes of data.